# Delete part of string in C (regex?)

Tags: c, regex, string, parsing, proxy

I have a long string with information like this:

```
"GET http://www.google.se/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.google.se\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0\r\n
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n
Keep-Alive: 115\r\n
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Cookie: PREF=ID=7d6a62c557413bc8:FF=0:TM=1327968040:LM=1327968040:S=U1A51rCRDDMTF295\r\n
Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n\r\n"
```

And i want to get rid of the keep-alive part under the Proxy-Connection..
This is what i'm doing so far:

1. getting the string (header) in to the function.
2. Creating a struct with two strings (header and host)
3. putting the host name from the header in the host part (obviously)
4. and putting the header in the header part.

And now i want to get rid of the keep-alive part before i put the header in the header-part of the struct.

Any ideas?

And here is some code of what i've done so far. I'm new to C so might not be the most beautiful of code you've seen..

```
struct ParsedHeader header_parser(char * input) {
  struct ParsedHeader h;
  int status;
  regex_t regex;
  char * result_begin = NULL;

  regcomp(&regex, "host:", REG_EXTENDED|REG_ICASE|REG_NOSUB);
  if((status = regexec(&regex, input, (size_t) 0, NULL, 0)) == 0) {
    char end = '\r';
    char * header = malloc(strlen(input));

    char * begin = "host:";

    size_t result_size = 0;
    memcpy(header, input, strlen(input));
    to_lower(input, header, strlen(input));
    result_begin = (strstr(header, begin) + 6);

    char * result_end = strchr(result_begin, end);
    result_end[0] = '\0';
    //char result[strlen(result_begin)] = result_begin;
    free(header);
  }
  regfree(&regex);

  h.header = input;
  h.host = result_begin;

  return h;
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you posted the most relevant parts of your code here, this question would get more attention.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of this specific `KeepAlive: 115` line, or any possible value for KeepAlive?

Comment: Error: Change your malloc to malloc(strlen(input)+1) since you need to allocate space for the terminating null.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to remove only the "Keep-Alive" string.  Do it like this:

```
// assume buffer contains the long input string
char *pBegin; 
char *pEnd;
pBegin = strstr(buffer, "Keep-Alive:");
if (pBegin)
{
    pEnd = strstr(pBegin, "\r\n");
    if (pEnd)
        strcpy(pBegin, pEnd+2);
}
```

However, if what you want to do is remove the "keep-alive" string from the Proxy-Connection header, a similar solution works:

```
char *pBegin; 
char *pEnd;
pBegin = strstr(buffer, "Proxy-Connection:");
if (pBegin)
{
    pBegin = strstr(pBegin, "keep-alive");
    if (pBegin)
        strcpy(pBegin, pBegin+strlen("keep-alive"));
}
```

Comment: I think you understood wrong: "I want to get rid of the keep-alive part under the Proxy-Connection". This seems like he'd rather like to modify the `Proxy-Connection` header.

Comment: Well, i solved the seg fault. was just a matter of lower case and upper case. but it wont still work.. the keep-alive part is still in there!

Comment: That's most likely case sensitivity again since the strstr function is case sensitive.  If you can lowercase the entire string first and then always pass lowercase to strstr, that will fix it.